# writing a record with $_SESSION values into a database table

Tags: php, mysql, session, record

I can't seem to write the values of my $_SESSION variable into a record of my database table which has an auto-incrementing Primary Key. I have looked in many places on the forum but cannot find the solution to my problem. My hunch is that I need to add something for the auto-increment to work, but I am not sure. The code I am using is shown below. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

// SESSION FILE
include ("sessionstart.inc");

echo "<html>
    <head><title>Reports-SESSION</title></head>
    <body>";

include ("misc.inc"); //THIS SETS $cxn AS MY VARIABLE TO CONNECT TO THE DATABASE

// SELECT THE DATABASE TO USE
mysqli_select_db($cxn,"carregistration") or die(mysqli_error($cxn));

// SET TEST VALUES IN $_SESSION VARIABLE
$_SESSION['OwnerCarIdentifier']='6Gh7J8';
$_SESSION['CarType']='station car';

// TEST TO SEE WHAT VALUES ARE NOW IN $_SESSION
foreach ($_SESSION as $field => $value)
{
    echo "$field = $value<br />\n";
}
// THIS CONFIRMS THAT THE TWO $_SESSION VALUES ARE THERE AND AS SET ABOVE

echo "<br />";

// NOW WRITE VALUES FROM $_SESSION INTO A NEW RECORD IN THE DATABASE
mysqli_query($cxn,"INSERT INTO 'car' (OwnerCarIdentifier,CarType) VALUES ('$_SESSION[OwnerCarIdentifier]','$_SESSION[CarType]')");

//ERROR CHECKING TO SEE IF THE DATA WERE SUCCESSFULLY RECEIVED BY THE DATABASE OR NOT.
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "The connection with the database failed." . mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}

// CLOSE THE RECORD
mysqli_close($cxn);

//DESTROY THE SESSION: THIS STATEMENT SHOULD APPEAR AT THE VERY END WHEN YOU HAVE STORED ALL THE FIELDS FOR A ROW IN THE DATABASE
session_destroy();


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make `die("INSERT INTO 'car' (OwnerCarIdentifier,CarType) VALUES ('$_SESSION[OwnerCarIdentifier]','$_SESSION[CarType]')");` after `
echo "<br />";` and let know result.

Comment: @Narek After having put your     die("INSERT INTO 'car' (OwnerCarIdentifier,CarType) VALUES ('$_SESSION[OwnerCarIdentifier]','$_SESSION[CarType]')");                       I am receiving this message: INSERT INTO 'car' (OwnerCarIdentifier,CarType) VALUES ('6Gh7J8','station car')

Comment: As you can see Query looks right, so problem not in $_SESSION. Check your DB structure, maybe wrong table fields name or something like that, but **not session problem**.

Answer (score 1):

First....

```
 mysqli_query($cxn,"INSERT INTO `car` (`OwnerCarIdentifier`, `CarType`) VALUES ('" .$_SESSION['OwnerCarIdentifier']."','".$_SESSION['CarType']."')");
```

Second... I hope your primary key in db is not `OwnerCarIdentifier` since you can't put an autoincrement over a string.

Third... Hope the data doesn't get in session from a form or something or you have a huge mysql injection there.

Comment: My Primary Key is indeed another (non-string) field than OwnerCarIdentifier. I do not understand what you are saying with "Hope the data doesn't get in session from a form or something or you have a huge mysql injection there". My data, indeed, are coming from a form.

Comment: Imagine some1 post in it's form in CarType field following string "'); DELETE FROM `users` WHERE 1;". Yeah will generate an error but also will delete the `users` table (presuming it exists). Or anyway... a simple ' breaks your query. Of course, presuming you didn't do do something before to escape the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
mysqli_query($cxn,"INSERT INTO 'car' (`OwnerCarIdentifier`,`CarType`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['OwnerCarIdentifier']."','".$_SESSION['CarType']."')");
```

This will be execute properly.

Comment: Sorry. I'm afraid that did not work either. I am now checking the database structure as @Narek suggests that might be where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO car VALUES('{$_SESSION['OwnerCarIdentifier']}','{$_SESSION['CarType']}' ");
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
     $sql = mysqli_query($cxn,"INSERT INTO 'car' (OwnerCarIdentifier,CarType) VALUES ('{$_SESSION[OwnerCarIdentifier]}','{$_SESSION[CarType]}')");

     if(mysqli_affected_rows($cxn) === 0)
     {
        eixt ("Error on insert");
     }
```